# How to close carbon Modal on save

Tags: reactjs, carbon-design-system

I'm using ModalWrapper from 'carbon-components-react'

On clicking Save, it is not closing the modal.
How to force it to close?

**See example codesandbox**
https://codesandbox.io/s/carbon-components-react-forked-n09un?file=/src/index.js

Comment: can you paste your code, please?

Comment: updated with example

Comment: where do you get the value of this property ```hasBeenSaved```?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **ModalWrapper**, you must add **shouldCloseAfterSubmit** to your ModalWrapper and return true in your **handleModalSave** function

```
// HandleModalSave
const handleModalSave = (data, ssdf) => {
  return true;
};

// ModalWrapper
<ModalWrapper
  buttonTriggerText="Save"
  modalHeading="Save Table"
  handleSubmit={handleModalSave}
  primaryButtonText={primaryButtonText}
  shouldCloseAfterSubmit
>
```

Comment: Did doesn't work. If I set open={false} the modal will still trigger and open, which is odd in itself. As its already false, setting it to false won't do anything.

Comment: I edited my answer, please check it, I think your problem is solved, you can use Modal component to handle open/close state yourself